# Old symfony site (1.0.17) broken when locale is lower case

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm trying to get the following website back up and running: [www.technospecials.be](http://www.technospecials.be) .
I'm developing a new website for this company, when all of a sudden their old website gave up and died. Or did it?

Turns out the page the front page links to may not work (http://www.technospecials.be/fr/pages/Home), but change the casing of the language and http://www.technospecials.be/FR/pages/Home . Magic!

So I need a band aid of sorts to fix the site for now.

I first tried setting up a urlrewrite rule, but I'm not convinced the urlrewrite module is working. Somehow I can't verify it, because every PHP file I upload only ever renders phpinfo() (Magic!).

After that I changed the following template: /apps/frontend/tenplates/langChoice.php to statically link the upper case URL, rather than generate the lower case ones. The markup in that template seemed like it would be the one used for the language choice page. No luck though; nothing changed. I deleted the entire contents of the cache folder. Should this work?  Reverse proxy cache?

I looked up the error messages in the PHP error log, and the problem seems to coincide with the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in /opt/www/technospecials/web/private/lib/symfony/i18n/sfMessageSource_XLIFF.class.php on line 300
```

Far as I can tell the $body variable is uninitialized in a method that deals with untranslated strings. Could this be a corrupt file that's being loaded from disk? Where do I look for it?

So now I don't know. This problem seems like it should be easy to fix. Does anyone have ideas as to:

- Why it is broken now, and
- How I should go about fixing it ?

I have access to FTP and SSH.

Comment: Why not just fix your link(s) so the locale is specified in the case that works?

Comment: I tried that, but the links won't update. I don't know enough about Symfony to dig into why not.
And even if it worked there are also lots of sites linking, bookmarks, indexed urls on Google etc.

Answer (score 0):

Strange how this could change just on itself. Are you aware that symfony uses the routing.yml file to define it's urls? Normally an url will route like www.symfony.com/module/action of the frontend app. I'm assuming NL is not a module so this should be described somewhere in the frontend/config/routing.yml. Possibly you can duplicate the NL/pages/Home rule and make one for the lowercase option.

Comment: Yes, I'd found the routing file. Most of the urls in there look like /:sf_culture/pages/:title though. And the ones that do include an explicit language are lower case.

I agree this is a very strange thing to change on itself. In fact: I suspect it didn't.

Comment: You get something usefull in log/error.log when opening the lowercase page? you could try making a `/nl/pages/:title` and in the params specify `sf_culture : NL`

Comment: Oh, you could look in the /lib/vendor/symfony/lib/i18n/data/ folder and see what exact the name of the dutch .dat file is. Seems very unlikely, but maybe it got changed to uppercase.

Comment: The error.log hasn't had anything written to it since march this year. The acces.log shows the requests though, logged with a 500 error. When I get a chance, I'll dig into the apache logs.

Comment: The dutch language version problem turned out to be a red herring: I simply upped the php memory limit and it worked. French version problem persists as originally described though.
I updated the original question with the php error message.

Comment: I can't comment on the question yet, so I'll do that here. Pretty crazy that the NL is fixed, but not the FR. If you didn't see them yet, you can find the files in apps/frontend/i18n/messages.fr.xml (or other app instead of 'fontend'). Not sure that'll help you, unless there's just a file with uppercase FR or something. As for fixing it, depending on what IDE you use, try a debbuger like xDebug and put a break somewhere in the sfMessageSource_XLIFF class.

Comment: Alright! Success! Turns out apps/frontend/i18n/messages.fr.xml had been corrupted somehow (double closing tags of the body). I'm assuming the /FR/pages/Home worked because the routing was case insensitive, but opening the message xml was case sensitive.
If you repost as an answer, I can accept it.